# Subclipse erases keychain access of command-line svn whenever it is used

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse

Here is the flow:

I'm using Catalina, Eclipse 2019-09 and SVN 1.10.4.

- Do an svn update on the terminal command-line => the keychain popup asks for your password. I hit Always Allow.
- From that point on I can do everything svn related on the command line without having to enter the password.
- Now if I go to subclipse and do an svn update, the command-line loses is and asks for the keychain password again.

Any hope for me?

Answer (score 0):

Subclipse has no control or influence on any of this. It just calls a SVN API which down in the lower levels is using the OSX keychain API.  My guess is that different versions of the SVN libraries exist and something in OSX keychain that tracks what libraries you have given permission changes.  I tend to use Homebrew and just have the single copy of the libraries installed. I do notice whenever the SVN version changes that I have to reauthorize to the keychain but other than that I have not see this problem. Can only assume you have more than one set of SVN libraries installed.

Ultimately it is the OSX keychain that is deciding to do this.